# How can I print bruma characters that are coming from json object JAVA

Tags: java, json, char, utf

I have a json and it contains burma language chars. When I want to get them, characters are changing. Here is my code:

```
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();                
            InputStream is  = connection.getInputStream();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(is, sw,"UTF-8");
            String s=sw.toString();
            JSONObject mainjobj= new JSONObject(s);
```

the string must contain burma chars normally but it is returning like:
'....,"name":"ဝါးကွဲထမ်းပိုး၊ ဆိုင်းပေါင်ကျိုးနှင့် ပုဆိုးညစ်တေ၊ ယောင်ထန်းစေ့မှုတ်၊","file_url":"ht....'

What is wrong with that code ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a font that can display those characters. A Unicode U+100D (java `\u100d`) is shown here as a boxed 10/0D.

A full Unicode font like MS Arial Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

That's what your SO question looks on my computer (Mac OS X, Chrome browser):

[image: Screenshot from your question]

That looks like perfect Burmese text to me. As [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen) said, you're probably missing a font that includes the Burmese characters.

BTW: The country is called "Burma" not "Bruma".

Comment: Thank you for answer and 'Burma' :D